# Dojo DataGrid autoHeight not working in IE9

Tags: css, datagrid, dojo

I am using Dojo 1.7 with an IE9 browser. I am trying to dynamically generate multiple DataGrids and append them to content inside a div. I am using the `autoHeight` property of the grid.

This works out fine in Chrome or Firefox. However, the grids are not displayed on IE until I set the height to a fixed amount.

How can I make autoHeight work in IE? I suspect its something to do with how IE9 treats height semantics.

Answer (score 2):

I've been dealing with this same issue until a few minutes ago: I am creating dynamic grids depending on how many items I have in a list and every grid is shown with autoHeight. The problem is nothing to do with Grids or its height.

I am not sure but IE interpret layers in a different way than other browsers, so you have to add them in a concrete way. Try to add the grid first to your DOM node (I mean a node that you also create dynamically over which you will append the grid), then add in last place this grid container to your HTML. It is working correctly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. I tried to find an alternate.

I followed this way and its working.

Add following property to

```
dojox.grid.datagrid
onShow: function(){if(grid)grid.setStore(store);}
```

And call `grid.onShow();`

```
  var grid= new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
    store : store,
    query : {
      sno : "*"
    },
    autoHeight:true,
    structure : columns,
    selectionMode : "Multiple",
    onShow: function(){if(grid)grid.setStore(store);}
  });

// This will fire the onShow event on grid.
grid.onShow();
```

Answer (score 0):

On IE, I had to ensure that I called startup on the dynamically added grid. e.g. if you add the grid in postCreate, try this:

```
startup: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);
    if (this.grid) this.grid.startup();
}
```

The grid can be fussy.  Even doing this, I still have height issues on IE (IE9) with autoHeight.  If I set an updated store after the fact, the height goes to 0.